# using for loop on mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have 2 tables on my db:
cat (id, catname)
link (id, name, url, cat)

I wanted to loop through the table `link` and output data by `cat`, here the actual code but id doesn't work anyway :)

```
    for ($i = 1; ; $i++)
    {
        $list = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM links WHERE category='$i'');
        while($row = $list->fetch_assoc()) {
            print $row["category"];
            print $row["name"].' ';
            print $row["url"];
            print '<br>';
        }
    }

    $list->free();
```

Is there a way we can get the `id` from table `cat` and use that to loop through the data in table `link`?
Thanks

Comment: Please provide the table structure

Comment: A dangerous loop because it will run forever. There is no upper limit on $i. And forever includes a lot of query statements.

Comment: JOIN the tables in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for so many requests inside the loop. There are JOIN statements in SQL for such cases:

```
$result = $mysqli->query('SELECT category.name AS cat_name, 
                               links.name,
                               links.url 
                          FROM category 
                          INNER JOIN links ON links.cat=category.id');

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    print $row["cat_name"];
    print $row["name"].' ';
    print $row["url"];
    print '<br>';
}

$result->close();
```